# cherrypy/apache server not releasing memory after function call ends

Tags: python, apache, memory, cherrypy

I've tried for a while to detect memory problems with cherrypy. Any web call to a function uses memory that when I run this command:

```
ps -u djotjog -o pid,rss,command | awk '{print $0}{sum+=$2} END {print "Total", sum/1024, "MB"}'
```

seems to remain used up permanently. I've tried to 'del' every object in the function before exiting. No effect. I was wondering if my class instance, which stores a lot of data - might be the problem. I use something like:

```
class Data:
    pass
ref_data = Data() 

... do stuff... make a stories_dict ...

ref_data.stories = stories_dict #dictionary 'id':'story' pairs
del stories_dict
```

In the end, I see 350MB still used each time I run the web-call, and after it reaches 500MB, it seems to spawn another cherrypy instance!

```
  PID   RSS COMMAND
10492   960 ps -u globamh1 -o pid,rss,command
10493   784 awk {print $0}{sum+=$2} END {print "Total", sum/1024, "MB"}
29833  1708 -bash
Total 3.37109 MB
```

LATER...

```
  PID   RSS COMMAND
12811  1164 /bin/sh cherryd.fcgi
12817 293788 /home4/globamh1/python-2.7.2/bin/python2.7     /home4/globamh1/.local/bin/cherryd -P modules -c cherryd.conf -f -i app
13195   984 ps -u globamh1 -o pid,rss,command
13196    16 awk {print $0}{sum+=$2} END {print "Total", sum/1024, "MB"}
29833  1708 -bash
Total 308 MB
```

Later still...

```
  PID   RSS COMMAND
 4053  5216 /home/globamh1/python-2.7.2/bin/python /home/globamh1/python-    2.7.2/ngo_prompter_2.py
 4091   988 ps -u globamh1 -o pid,rss,command
 4092   784 awk {print $0}{sum+=$2} END {print "Total", sum/1024, "MB"}
12817 1111616 /home4/globamh1/python-2.7.2/bin/python2.7    /home4/globamh1/.local/bin/cherryd -P modules -c cherryd.conf -f -i app
29833  1716 -bash
32413  1168 /bin/sh cherryd.fcgi
32414 576792 /home4/globamh1/python-2.7.2/bin/python2.7 /home4/globamh1/.local/bin/cherryd -P modules -c cherryd.conf -f -i app
Total 1658.48 MB
```

So to wrap this up into some specific questions:

- how quickly should python's garbage collector work?
- does cherrypy or apache do something weird to keep data persistent?
- how can I trust cherrypy to respond to multiple requests if it is using so much memory? I already see that it ignores some requests.
- is this a server configuration problem?

Is THIS the same problem? 
[Memory not released by python cherrypy application on linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3290754/memory-not-released-by-python-cherrypy-application-on-linux)

And if yes, how do I configure that solution on a shared hosting site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the sample code you show, there's very little to be collected. In particular:

```
ref_data.stories = stories_dict
```

That makes ref_data.stories and stories_dict both refer to the same, large dataset. Even if you delete stories_dict, since ref_data.stories is still a reference to that same dict, it will not be garbage-collected until ref_data.stories is deleted (or ref_data is deleted):

```
del ref_data.stories # remove the attribute
del ref_data # delete the instance and all of its attributes
```

Otherwise, the only thing left to be garbage-collected when stories_dict is deleted is the pointer to that dictionary (just a few bytes, probably).

> How quickly should python's garbage collector work?

I'm not sure there are guarantees, but in my experience, the garbage collector runs immediately when any object is `del`ed or a function exits.

> does cherrypy or apache do something weird to keep data persistent?

I suspect not. Do you not see this behavior if you run the same routines directly from the interpreter?

> how can I trust cherrypy to respond to multiple requests if it is using so much memory? I already see that it ignores some requests.
>   is this a server configuration problem?

If your application fundamentally uses more memory than the system has available if requests are handled in parallel, you will need to find some way to synchronize the responses across requests. Another option is to configure apache/cherrypy to only serve one request at a time. I believe this is part of the WSGI configuration (how many processes/threads to allocate). If you limit the number of processes/threads to 1, then CherryPy will only serve one request at a time.

Comment: From the server bash command line - nothing persists when running python [filename].py... Deleting ref_data did nothing to the persistent memory usage.

Comment: I've narrowed the memory problems down to something involving mysqldb - and posted a more concise description here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13612050/mysqldb-usage-in-cherrpy-app-leads-to-massive-persistent-memory-usage-on-server

Comment: IS there a systematic way to see a list of all data objects in memory when a program ends, and their sizes, so that I can route out the source of the persistent data usage? Something stays in memory probably because cherrypy stays in memory.